# Sort text data without a delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have to do the following in excel. I have a multiple text files of the same format: (see below)

---

```
- Samplefile 
- 1)Step 1
- XYZ
- 2)Step 2
- ABC
- 3)Step 3
- ABC1
```

---

```
- Name: Samplefile2
- 1)Step 1
- XYZ2
- 2)Step 2
- ABC2
- 3)Step 3
- DEF2
```

I wanted to write a code to import all the files and give me a final output as below in different excel columns

```
 1. Name         Step1  Step2  Step3
 3.  Samplefile   XYZ    ABC    ABC1
 4.  Samplefile2  XYZ2   ABC2   DEF2
```

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from doing this?  Please be specific.  Right now this is just a specification and not a question.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thanks for looking at this. I am just expecting some tips to get started on this. 

Can I upload an excel file to be more specific? I am not seeing an option for that. Please, let me know if this is more clear. I am facing the following problem:
a. How to apply delimiter for rows? XYZ is below Step 1 and not next to it
b. If I use something like Vlookup, How can I differentiate what is under sample file1 and samplefile2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you phrase a question like "How do I write a code.. to do X" that is an unacceptable question in SO. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to start writing building the code and if you have a *specific* question about something in the code and ask about it you will get all the help you need. No one is going to spoon feed you on how to _"write the code to build a solution to your specification_ (e.g.: How do I open text files in VBA is a good question). How to build a program to sort text in multiple files in VBA is not a good question.

Comment: The first thing to figure out is maybe how to loop over files in a folder using `Dir()` and then how to read the content of each file line-by-line.  Googling either of those should get you good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

I got some progress with this.I am able to import the files and split it.

For my next step, I wanted some help in modifying this code so that I can change the  of the sheet that I import the recipes files  to sheet 1, sheet 2 and so on, instead of the text file namme?

See code below:

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"

    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter

        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler



End Sub
```